# Flutter Scroll to List name

Tags: flutter, dart

I need help scrolling to the name on the list, which I previously chose on a previous screen. For example, if I choose "List 2" in the previous screen, I need the list 2 to be placed at the top of the screen
This is my code
https://gist.github.com/cristianfb1989/808a0b5663821b097ba9072535f24bb3

[image: Simple List]

[image: Complex List]

Comment: How do you get /store those item and list values ?

Comment: @NaveenAvidi Those values are hardcoded, but in theory they're dynamic lists

Comment: I mean List<String> or Map or API ??

Comment: @NaveenAvidi List<Widget>